# Grammar checker at Lyx on Windows 7

Tags: lyx, windows, grammar

I know that there are some tools which can check for grammar mistakes if you run lyx under linux, so I wonder if there is any similar tool compatible with windows

Comment: Hi and welcome! When asking questions like this, it is useful if you mention what you already know. This is good because (1) you will get advice that you don't yet know, and (2) it is helpful to others that find your question.

Comment: Have you read the page http://wiki.lyx.org/Tools/LyX-GrammarChecker ? In particular, this quote is relevant: "I have not tested this script under Windows, but it should just work if you are using Cygwin" ?

Comment: @scottkosty I have already read that statement. However, I don't want to use Cygwin, mostly because I am afraid of compatibility issues and problems in lyx efficiency

Comment: I have not heard of any issues of either kind. Also, `.lyx` files are completely cross-platform. However, my point was more that it would be helpful if you would put such information in your question next time.